# Observing network change event in linux application

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, events

I have an application where I wanted to get notified if there is any network change that has occured. I have found a bunch of solution like

- using **NetworkManager** or **systemd-network** service (which I do not prefer because I do not know If these services are installed and running on the users system or not)
- using **Netlink socket** : Here all the network change event  information is queued in the netlink message queue, and a handler in our application will fetch the data from this queue and process it. We have to use a while(1) loop, which periodically processes data from this queue. (This approach requires to constantly poll for any updates from the queue)

Other platforms like windows and mac have observer APIs where we can subscribe for the network change event and our application gets notified in a handler whenever this event takes place. I m looking if something similar in available in linux?

**Edit**: Since NetworkManager is present by default on Ubuntu distro, I can use the DBus implementation because NetworkManager broadcast events via D-Bus when the system's network status changes. By network change I mean to monitor for when the system is connected, disconnected or even switched from one Wifi/ethernet network to another on ubuntu.
I am wanted to identify dbus event in a cpp program.

Comment: I didn't quiet understand your question ... Do you want a NetworkManager based solution? Like e.g. `nmcli monitor`? or maybe something like `dbus-monitor --session --monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.NetworkMonitor'"`?

Comment: no, I want a general solution which runs on any system, and not depend on the whether the user has some dependency installed or not, like in the case of NetworkManager where it needs to be first installed on the system to be able to use it. I m looking If there is some event observer to which I can subscribe, so that my application gets notified of any network change.

Comment: Then you probably need to look into kernel events ... But, I doubt even that will give you a standardized cross-platform compatible solution ...  NetworkManager is installed on every Ubuntu by default any way.

Comment: Does NetworkManager give some event to which I can register to be notified on the network change?

Comment: What kind of network changes do you wish to monitor … Please, mention them and try to be specific as much as possible so we can suggest solutions that will work for your specific needs.

Comment: I have updated the question. can u please check?

Comment: For D-Bus usage examples, please see the examples section at the project's page e.g. https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/main/examples/C/glib/monitor-nm-state-gdbus.c ... And I'm afraid there is not an easy straight forward single command method in D-Bus like it is the case with `nmcli` for example.

Comment: Recall that this is the FOSS World. Read `man apt-get dpkg`. Use `dpkg -S` to find the package, and `apt-get source`